# docker под windows 10 на macbook - как включить виртуализацию в биосе?

Tags: windows, docker, macbook

Не запускается docker под windows 10 на макбуке, а вместо этого выдает сообщение о том, что надо в биосе включить виртуализацию. Но как это сделать на маке?

Answer (score 0):

Сначала загрузись через `macOS X`, зайди в `Системные настройки` -> `Загрузочный том` и выбери систему для загрузки компьютера `Boot Camp` и компьютер должен перезагрузится с Windows + с включенной виртуализацией